# Xcode/iOS: How to hide Navigation- AND ToolBar on scroll down?

Tags: ios, xcode, toolbar, navigationbar

I would like to hide both bars on scroll down on my iPhone. When I scroll up, they should appear again.. How can I handle this?

Comment: Did you try to use `setToolbarHidden:animated:` and `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` in `scrollViewDidScroll:` when the x value of the `contentOffset` increases.

Comment: Please use English here. This is a platform for people from all over the world. When we start to talk in German, a lot of people can't follow. When you need advice in German send me an email. I think, to find my email address shouldn't be difficult with the information you can find in my profile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted answer does not work for me, as `scrollViewWillBeginScroll:` is not a delegate method.

Instead I do

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BarsShouldHide" object:self];

}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
                 willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if(!decelerate)
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BarsShouldUnhide" 
                                                            object:self];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"BarsShouldUnhide"
                                                        object:self];
}
```

Anywhere in the app objects can listen for this notification,like

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"BarsShouldHide" 
                                                      object:nil
                                                       queue:nil
                                                  usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        //hide tab bar with animation;
    }];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:@"BarsShouldUnhide" 
                                                      object:nil
                                                       queue:nil
                                                  usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        //Unhide tab bar with animation;
    }];
}
```

This code will hide the bars for any scroll. if you want to have only on down, the same `locationOffset` trick as in the accepted answer should work.

Answer (score 7):

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginScroll :(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
      if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < lastOffset.y) {
                 [toolBar setHidden:YES];
                 [[[self navigationController] navigationBar] setHidden:YES];
      } else{
                 // unhide
      }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll :(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
      /// blah blah
      lastOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
}
```

**Note** : `lastOffset` is an `CGPoint` and it goes in your header file: `@Interface`.

Comment: mdominick: what do you mean with "iVar"?

Comment: I am quite new to this :S how do I define this variable? is it a NSString?

Comment: It's a CGPoint: so CGPoint lastOffset; It goes in your header file: @Interface Blah : NSObject { GCPoint lastOffset; }

Comment: I can't find ```scrollViewWillBeginScroll``` method in ```UIScrollViewDelegate```

Comment: There is also a typo in this code: `scrollView.contentOffset.y < lastOffSet.y` needs to be `scrollView.contentOffset.y < lastOffset.y` lastOffset not lastOffSet (capital S)

Comment: This is the way to declare lastOffset? @property (nonatomic) CGPoint lastOffset;

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution in Swift; it works beautifully

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let navController: UINavigationController = self.navigationController!
    if self.collectionView.panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(self.view).y <= 0.0 {
        defaultCenter.postNotificationName("stuffShouldHide", object: self)
    } else {
        defaultCenter.postNotificationName("stuffShouldUnhide", object: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might check this, available from iOS8, i think this is the reverse of what you are looking for...but worth checking as it is something standard and this is how Safari works.

> Swift
>
> var hidesBarsOnSwipe: Bool
>
> Objective-C
>
> @property(nonatomic, readwrite, assign) BOOL hidesBarsOnSwipe
>   Discussion
>
> When this property is set to YES, an upward swipe hides the navigation
>   bar and toolbar. A downward swipe shows both bars again. If the
>   toolbar does not have any items, it remains visible even after a
>   swipe. The default value of this property is NO.