# XCode/iOS: setToolbarHidden:animated creates new unwanted toolbar?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to achieve something similar to user of this post:

[Xcode/iOS: How to hide Navigation- AND ToolBar on scroll down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180446/xcode-ios-how-to-hide-navigation-and-toolbar-on-scroll-down)

I'm able to hide (or unhide using NO) the navigation bar successfully using the code:

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

However, when I attempt to hide the toolbar using the code:

```
[[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

Nothing happens. I then noticed when unhiding the toolbar that I received an additional blue toolbar that I didn't realize existed. This screenshot shows this:

[Screenshot](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11692691/host/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%20Nov%207,%202012%2010.54.36%20PM.png)

I do not want the blue bar. What I am trying to do is hide or unhide the Black toolbar with the icons on it. (the UITabBar).

I think what I need to do is somehow I need to access the navigation controller of one of the parent view controllers and call the setToolbarHidden on the navigation controller of that view. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I've tried the following and all seem to have no effect:

```
[[[self parentViewController] navigationController] setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];

or

[[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController] navigationController] setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

My view controller storyboard consists of the following:

The InitialViewController is a TabBarViewController. It contains three children. One of those children is a UINavigationController. This navigation controller gets several UITableViewController pushed onto it, and eventually a UIViewController is pushed. This last UIViewController is what is seen in the screenshot.

Rough Layout:

- TabBarViewController

  - UIViewController
  - UITableViewController
  - UINavigationController

    - UITableViewController

      - UITableViewController

        - UITableViewController

          - UIViewController

I've tried using

```
[self parentViewController] parentViewController] parentViewController] ...
```

to attempt to get back to the top, but this hasn't seemed to work either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: wait, what? which of the vc's in your rough layout are siblings on the tab bar? how are they related, hierarchically?

Comment: I've reformatted the post, hopefully the layout is more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here might be related to `UITabBarController` not having a `UIToolbar`. The `setToolbarHidden:` method will only apply to the `UINavigationController`'s *built-in* toolbar ([see Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). If it's the `UITabBarController`'s tab bar that you actually want to hide, take a look at [this post which links to a method using `UIView` animations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1996944/1166029) directly on the `UITabBar`.

Comment: actually, maybe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10474248/1166029) is better for you. (From the same thread.)

Comment: I ended up finding a project that does exactly what I was trying to do. It is available here:

https://github.com/tonymillion/ExpandingView

Comment: yup. and the code in that project does exactly what's described in the linked post. nice find, I'll probably start using that!