# How to hide navigation bar and tab bar while scrolling table view in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I have problem with hide tab bar as navigation bar. My requirement is hide both navigation bar and tab bar at same time when I m scrolling table view..my navigation bar is working properly as requirement but tab bar is no not responding to the same....is there any one can help me to sort it out please....????

I m using NJKSCROLLFULLSCREEN for reference..http://GitHub.com/ninjakin/NJKSrollfullScreen
 Here is some screenshots of my project..[image]this is what the problem with my tab bar when it hides..!
this is main screen and I want it will look like!

[image: This is my problem]

[image]

[image: I want to show my view like this]

[image]

Comment: Have you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180446/xcode-ios-how-to-hide-navigation-and-toolbar-on-scroll-down ?

Comment: I have checked this but still not useful, still i'm facing same issue

Comment: @LuaiKalkatawi can u plz help more

Comment: maybe you should check your scrollview's height and constraints.

Comment: @kocakmstf I already checked it, but its fine

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/HidingNavigationBar

> HidingNavigationBar supports hiding/showing of the following view 
>   elements:
>
> UINavigationBar UINavigationBar and an extension UIView
>   UINavigationBar and a UIToolbar UINavigationBar and a UITabBar