# Hide show top view when scroll in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a custom view as my collection view header. But of course when I scroll, the header disappears until I scroll back to the top.

An example of what I want to achieve is like the current Facebook app. Where the "LIVE, Photo, Check in" view hides when you scroll down, and returns once you scroll upwards a bit.

[image: example]

It's like this. But I just want the live, photo and check in bar hidden and show while scroll.

My current approach is just add as a collection view header.

Comment: It has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28631985/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-and-tab-bar-while-scrolling-table-view-in-ios

Comment: But I want to hide the header view. Not the navbar

Comment: can you post screenshot of your problem and codes?

Comment: Check my edited question

Comment: Add a gesture recognizer to handle scrolling events on collection view. Detect direction of gesture to hide/unhide the header view.

Comment: I can imagine the direction. But how to do the hide/unhide as a collection view header

Comment: I would suggest remove the header view out of the collection view and create it as separate view on top of the collection view. Now while scrolling change alpha/ translate the independent header view accordingly.

Comment: Hey did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I am doing something very similar, I have a small view acting as a header and then I have a larger view called contentView in which I put a uicollectionview. I want the header to dissapear and appear when ever I scroll down but I am not sure how to implement this behaviour.

Answer (score 11):

Here is code for hiding navigation bar with scroll

```
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            //
            contentOffSet = self.channelsCollView.contentOffset.y;
        }

        func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            //

            let scrollPos = self.channelsCollView.contentOffset.y ;

            if(scrollPos >= contentOffSet ){
                //Fully hide your toolbar
                UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                    //
                    //write a code to hide
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
                }, completion: nil)
            } else {
                //Slide it up incrementally, etc.
                UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                    //
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
                }, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use these libraries, which manages hiding and showing of Navigation bar as user scrolls :

- [HidingNavigationBar](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/HidingNavigationBar)
- [AMScrollingNavbar](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar)

Another way is to use this function in your `viewWillAppear`

```
if let navigationController = self.navigationController as? ScrollingNavigationController {
    navigationController.followScrollView(tableView, delay: 30.0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it is working in my project:

```
self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true;
```

Comment: does that mean my custom view must be in my navigation bar? Sorry but I'm confused with this approach.

Comment: did you try this ?

Comment: Yes but for some reason my navigation bar wasn't hiding, it worked for the first vc on the stack but the subsequent vc's navbar won't hide. Also, even in the first vc, my header is still there.

Comment: It's a show segue. One view controller down the stack from the root